# Rake -- Watch for Changes

Tags: rake

Is there a way using Rake to watch depedencies for changes and execute tasks automatically?

For example, given the following `Rakefile`:

```
file 'main.o' => ["main.c", "greet.h"] do
  sh "cc -c -o main.o main.c"
end

file 'greet.o' => ['greet.c'] do
  sh "cc -c -o greet.o greet.c"
end

file "hello" => ["main.o", "greet.o"] do
  sh "cc -o hello main.o greet.o"
end
```

It would be great if when I changed `greet.c` or `main.c` then `hello` would automatically execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK rake doesn't support watching files and directories with a continuous compilation approach.

The buildr project implements a [continuous compilation task](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/buildr/trunk/lib/buildr/core/cc.rb?view=markup) for java which you can get inspired by to do the job for your project.

Also, it looks like [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) might help there. See the guard github profile for implementations using guard. There's even a Rake extension to [do what you want!](https://github.com/guard/guard-rake)

Answer (score 0):

There is also rerun https://github.com/alexch/rerun. You can do `rerun rake` to watch and run the default task.